# How to write Unicode text into a Python file object

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

Simply put, the following code:

```
f.write(u'Río Negro')
```

raises the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What can I do?
I'm using Python 2.7.3.

Comment: use .encode('utf-8') on the string?

Comment: You could search SO with your error code, there's 1,750+ results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode your string. Try this:

```
f.write(u'Río Negro'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: it assumes that `f` is a binary file (`'wb'` mode on Python 3).

Answer (score 5):

Using [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) from the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module will eliminate the need for you to manually encode:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(u'Río Negro')
```

In Python 3, this functionality is built in to [the standard `open` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(u'Río Negro')
```

Comment: This.  In Python 3, this functionality is provided by the `open()` built-in.

Comment: `io.open()` should be used instead of `codecs.open()`. Its behavior is the same as `open()` on Python 3 (where `io.open is open`).